# Out of Memory in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, memory, out-of-memory

I have got two huge matrices `dat1`=87093*59 and `dat2`=99802*59. I tried to do following operation `R=dat1*dat1'` but MATLAB throws me an error

`??? Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.`

I have increased Java Heap Memory to 2012Mb but still the problem repeats. Can anyone help me out.
system config: windows 7-64bit, 8gb ram, MATLAB:r2010a-32bit version

Answer (score 3):

Given `dat1` is 87093x59, by doing `R=dat1*dat1'`, the output would be 87093x87093. Say you really meant `dat1*dat2'`, it's even worse, 87093x99802.

Assuming `dat1` is double precision (8 bytes per element), `dat1*dat1'` is 60,681,525,192 bytes (about 60GB). With `dat1*dat2'` it's close to 69 GB. I'd say give up or re-evaluate your approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate. It's completely my mistake..I should have looked at the matrix size.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jconsole or jvisualvm which are bundled in the bin folder of your JDK.  Then view your running java process.  It could be that your PermGen is the culprit here OR possibly a memory leak, in which case you can dump the memory via these tools and use a heap analysis tool to find out what might be causing the extreme memory usage.